# PHP/MYSQL counting orders

Tags: php, mysql

Here is database table:

[image: Users]

[image: Order_items]

```
$sql[2] = "SELECT u.* , oi.* , COUNT(oi.user_id) AS count 
           FROM users u, order_items oi 
           WHERE u.id=oi.user_id ";
$result3= mysqli_query($conn,$sql[2]) or die(mysqli_error());
if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
        echo $record['count'];
    }
}
```

I want to count how much order have every user. Example: Like Thomas have 3 order, but my code is writing 4, i want to write Thomas (3), Gracian(1). Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please, use formatted text instead of images. Also, with that sample data, what's the expected result?

Comment: the result is: 4 (thats all, i think its counting the rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT u.id,
       COUNT(oi.user_id) AS orderCount
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN order_items oi
    ON u.id = oi.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

The reason we count `user_id` from the `order_items` table is because of the edge case where a given user has no orders.  In this case, we want to make sure that his count would appear as zero.  The `COUNT` function ignores `NULL`s, which is what we want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen something wrong with this select, cause the result is: 3111

Comment: I think your data is the problem actually.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope its working fine, i just realize now COUNT is set default value to 1, and its working fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to perform the sql query using subqueries:

`SELECT id,
email, 
address,
name, 
(SELECT count(user_id) FROM order_items WHERE user_id = users.id) AS orderCount FROM users;`

Comment: and whats happend if i want to add one more row from another table (products). want to ID from products table, then p.ID = oi.product_id (order_items)

Comment: @FaragoRoland What's the property of the products that you want? Is it count too?

Comment: No. I have another table (Products: ID, product_name, price) and i want to  get quantity (from order_items) * price (from products table). Example: 5*20 = 100 (like 5 ordered item* price (20/each))

Comment: If I understood well, your question is about knowing how many orders performed by each user.
Now, would you like to know the total cost of each users orders? @FaragoRoland

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean

Comment: I'm not sure, however, try to add the following to the above query after `As orderCount`: `,COUNT((select price from products where id = order_items.product_id)) AS totalCost`

Comment: its not working unfortunately, maybe another tip? trying with this : $sql[2] = "SELECT *, (SELECT count(user_id) FROM order_items WHERE user_id = users.id) AS orderCount, COUNT((select 
price from products where id = order_items.product_id)) AS totalCost FROM users";